# hooks.py missing with charm helpers

Tags: juju

I was trying to create a python charm using charm helpers [Documentation](https://charm-helpers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#installing-charm-tools).

An empty charm has been successfully created but I was Unable to import hooks.py 
in to the directory structure.

```
root@juju:~/charms/precise# tree catebash/
catebash/
├── config.yaml
├── hooks
│   ├── config-changed
│   ├── install
│   ├── relation-name-relation-broken
│   ├── relation-name-relation-changed
│   ├── relation-name-relation-departed
│   ├── relation-name-relation-joined
│   ├── start
│   ├── stop
│   └── upgrade-charm
├── icon.svg
├── metadata.yaml
├── README.ex
└── revision

1 directory, 14 files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation is actually horribly outdated. Your generated charm is how they were written in juju 1.x. They used symbolic links so the different hooks would link to a general hooks.py file which you have to manually add. The hook files would all end up calling `hooks.py`. 
An example of this kind of charm can be found [here](https://git.launchpad.net/mongodb-charm/tree/hooks).

The new way to create charms is to create layered charms so you avoid writing a lot of duplicate code. To get started install the charm utilities:

`sudo snap install charm`

Create a charm

`charm create`

And then follow [this](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/developer-layer-example) documentation for an explanation of these types of charms.

Comment: sorry for getting back late. 
So, is the layered approach actually replacement of hooks? 
And I want to create a charm using some shell commands. Can you please suggest which layer should be present in the layer.yaml file and how should my approach be?

Comment: The layered approach makes you use a base layer named [layer-basic](https://github.com/juju-solutions/layer-basic), this layer will create the hooks. For your layer.yaml you'll need `layer:basic` and the rest is up to what your charm needs. Bash is not really used all that much with reactive but a small example for the reactive file can be found [here](https://charmsreactive.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bash-reactive.html).